# Does the incenter divide the triangle into a ratio of 2:1?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles, pythagorean-triples

I'm trying to get the radius of the circle.

First I use the Pythagorean theorem $13^2=5^2+x^2$ and $x=12$. Then I know the height of the triangle. To get the radius i use the Pythagorean theorem $r^2=5^2+(\frac{1}{3}\cdot12)^2$.

But here comes the problem, isn't the red part $\frac{1}{3}$ of the height, as the ratio of the incircle is $2:1$? My classmates don't agree, so who's right?

The triangle:

[image: The triangle]

**Edit:** Is the black dot in the triangle the incenter or centroid?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please use the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Why must "the red part 1/3 of the height"? Consider a very *slender* isosceles triangle inscribed in the circle.

Comment: You're thinking of the centroid. The incenter does not satisfy this relation.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Is the black dot the centroid or the incenter, as for me it looks like the incenter and centroid always are located at the same place.

Comment: The centroid is the intersection of the medians, and the incenter is the intersection of the angle bisectors. There's a big difference.

Comment: How do they differ?

Comment: So the centroid divides the side in two halves whereas the incenter divides the angle in two?

Comment: @Peter98: Coincidentally, [another recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4000544/409) asked the same kind of thing (w/ legs $14$ instead of $13$), and that user was likewise confused about the difference between incenters & centroids. (If you're that user, then know that reposting a question is not the appropriate way to call more attention to it, or to circumvent closure; rather, you should edit the previous version to improve its quality. If you're *not* that user, then maybe the source of the question should try harder to instill an appreciation of different triangle centers. :)

Comment: No it's not me:). But do you have an answer to my question?

Comment: @Peter98: BTW, a comment to that other question included a link to the Math is Fun ["Triangle Centers"](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/triangle-centers.html) page, which should help clear up confusion on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

The circumradius R can be found (if we let a,b,c be the sides and A=area) with the formula
$$R=\frac{abc}{4A}=\frac{10\cdot13\cdot13}{4(5\cdot12)}
=\frac{1690}{240}\approx 7.041666667$$
The "red" part of your diagram is then
$\quad 12-7.041666667=4.958333333\quad$
so the ratio is more like $\space7:5\space$ than $\space2:1.\space$ The eye views proportions incorrectly, often making lower "heights" appear greater than they are.

[Here](https://mathalino.com/reviewer/derivation-of-formulas/derivation-of-formula-for-radius-of-circumcircle)
and [here](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223429573)
and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumradius.html)
are links discussing the circumcircle radius you seek and below is a picture.

[image]